# Create and download text file in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, android-download-manager

I want to convert a string to a text file on the same side of the client(App) and download it to my phone. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you provide a code snippet of what you are doing that isn't working?

Comment: I used to try to save the file with react-native-fs, but I ran into a lot of problems, so I decided to use this download method and still haven't found a solution.
I can download the file from the server with rn-fetch-blob, but not from the client

Answer (score 0):

You can use **react-native-fs** for this task. It provides native filesystem access for react-native.

```
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.txt';

// write the file
RNFS.writeFile(path, 'your text comes here', 'utf8')
  .then((success) => {
    console.log('FILE WRITTEN!');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

**This might help you:**

```
var fs = require('react-native-fs');

  const readFile = async () => {
  fs.mkdir(fs.ExternalDirectoryPath + '/test')
  .then(() => downloadWithRNFS())
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  const downloadWithRNFS = async () => {
  const options = {
  fromUrl: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/header_logo.png',
  toFile: `${fs.ExternalDirectoryPath}/test/test.txt`,
};
    fs.downloadFile(options)
      .promise.then(res => {
        console.log('downloadWithRNFS', res);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
```